# Matrix norm identity. Understanding inequallity.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-norms

Let **A** $\in R^{m\times n}$. What dose it mean when the book then write **A** : $R^{n} \rightarrow R^{m}$?

I try to understand this inequality:
$\frac{1}{\sqrt m} \|\mathbf{A}\|_1 \le \|\mathbf{A}\|_2 \le \sqrt n \|\mathbf{A}\|_1$

I do not understand why is should be $\sqrt n$ and $\sqrt m$ on the other side... so I try to understand the calculation here:
[Inequality between 2 norm and 1 norm of a matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1497800/inequality-between-2-norm-and-1-norm-of-a-matrix?answertab=createdasc#tab-top)

They say,

> We have this, $\mathbf{A} : R^{n} \rightarrow R^{m}$

I understand why we get square root of a constant, the length of x vector in the definition of the norm, ut when should the constant be $\sqrt n$ and $\sqrt m$?

Comment: $m \times n$ matrices can be viewed as linear maps from $R^n$ (vectors in $n$-dimensional space) to $R^m$ (vectors in $m$-dimensional space) via $v \mapsto Av$.

Comment: I still cannot see when it should be square root on m or n...

Comment: **A** $\in R^{m\times n}$, so it is a mxn-matrix. ||A x||_2 or ||A x||_inf, vector x is m-elements long, right? So, how do I get n?

Comment: The vector Ax had length m.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the linked proof, the constants arise from these two specific steps: $$\Vert A\Vert_1\Vert x\Vert_1 \le \sqrt n \Vert A\Vert_1\Vert x\Vert_2$$ and $$\Vert Ax\Vert_1\le \sqrt m \Vert Ax\Vert_2.$$

In the first one, $x$ lives in $\Bbb R^n$, which is why $\Vert x\Vert_1 \le \sqrt n\Vert x\Vert_2$ with an $n$ in the constant.

In the second, $Ax$ is now the vector we consider, and it lives in $\Bbb R^m$, which is why the constant uses $m$ this time.

Comment: Absolutely! That make sense!

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)

Comment: But do you see why $\|abs(A)\|_2 \le \sqrt{min(m, n)}\|A\|_2$? I get: $\|abs(A)\|_2 \le \sqrt{mn}\|A\|_2$

Comment: Solved! Use the relation between $\|A\|_2$ and $\|A\|_F$